# Why does variadic template not work in template introduction but work in requires-clause? ConceptName{T,U,V,W} <-- template<typename ...T>

Tags: c++, templates, variadic-templates, c++-concepts

We have:

```
template <typename ...T> concept bool Numerics = ( std::is_arithmetic_v<T> && ... ) ;
template <typename T>    concept bool Numeric  =   std::is_arithmetic_v<T>;
```

So we can apply type constraints with a requires-clause like this:

```
template <typename T, typename U, typename V, typename W> requires Numerics<T,U,V,W>
auto foo(T arg1, U arg2, V arg3, W arg4) {
    return arg1 + arg2 + arg3 + arg4;
}
```

But we can not write in template introduction format like this:

```
// err: no match concept
// 
// Numerics{T,U,V,W}
// auto foo2(T arg1, U arg2, V arg3, W arg4) {
//     return arg1 + arg2 + arg3 + arg4;
// }
```

Having to explicitly define fixed number of arguments instead:

```
template <typename T, typename U, typename V, typename W>
                         concept bool Numeric4 =   Numerics<T,U,V,W>;

Numeric4{T,U,V,W}
auto foo3(T arg1, U arg2, V arg3, W arg4) {
    return arg1 + arg2 + arg3 + arg4;
}
```

Why doesn't `template <typename ...T> concept` work in template introduction format while work in requires-clause?

[LIVE](https://godbolt.org/g/b89wCh)

Comment: Related to [why-does-putting-concept-to-type-specifier-fail-type-deduction-when-the-same-con](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48341724/why-does-putting-concept-to-type-specifier-fail-type-deduction-when-the-same-con)

Answer (score 1):

First, note that this syntax has been removed from the Concepts TS in its [latest draft](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2017/p0734r0.pdf).

---

In the [previous draft](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2017/n4674.pdf), this syntax was defined in [temp.intro] and is well-defined:

```
Numerics{T,U,V,W}
auto foo2(T arg1, U arg2, V arg3, W arg4) {
    return arg1 + arg2 + arg3 + arg4;
}
```

should, for each *introduced-parameter*, adjust the parameter pack in `Numerics` by its pattern, and declare a template parameter based on that pattern. So this should be equivalent to:

```
template <typename T, typename U, typename V, typename W> // per [temp.intro]/2
     requires Numerics<T,U,V,W> // per [temp.intro]/5
auto foo2(T arg1, U arg2, V arg3, W arg4) {
    return arg1 + arg2 + arg3 + arg4;
}
```

There are further examples in this section which illustrate that this should work. Per this draft, the code is well-formed.

---

That said, as previously noted, the syntax has been removed from the TS and does not appear in the C++20 working draft. It may or may not be added in the future, in this form or otherwise.